# Are there any scenarios based on "Hound of the Baskervilles"?

Tags: story

Are there any good scenarios based on the classic "Hound of the Baskervilles" story?

The actual setting (Call of Ctulhu, D&D, whatever) isn't even that important as I plan to adapt it to my own setting anyway, but would be nice to be able to start from a solid story.

Edit: just to be clear, I'm not really looking for a literal scenario based on the Hounds story, I can pick up the Holmes story for that. Rather, any interpretations of this story in a fantasy/horror style would be the idea.

Comment: More like the thematic elements surrounding the story. I always found it quite a chilling story and would like to be able to reproduce it in a fantasy/horror setting.

Comment: As a pointer: look for Call of Cthulhu stuff featuring the Hound(s) of Tindalos. (There aren't many such scenarios). This creature is close, in feel, to the Hound of the Baskervilles.

Comment: Edited it with more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Howls in the Night](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=9110), a 2e D&D Ravenloft adventure, is very Baskervillian.

"The Mists of Ravenloft draw close, surrounding unfortunate travelers in their clammy embrace. When they part, they reveal the land of Mordent, a domain of rolling moors and woods, beautiful by day and terrifying by night.
A new danger lurks in the haunted moors: hounds whose mournful howls and murderous jaws trap the townsfolk in their homes at night. At the heart of it all lies a curse laid a century ago, and a tale of bitter tragedy.
Even now, you can hear the howls in the night...

Howls in the Night is a dark fantasy murder mystery - but one in which the victim has been dead for 100 years! Alternate adventure backgrounds allow the Dungeon Master to choose one of four possible conclusions."

Answer (score 2):

I believe Cthulhu by Gaslight has a Holmes-esque story called "The Yorkshire Horrors"... As far as I can recall it involves running around the moors trying to thwart some cosmic menace. It incorporates Conan Doyle's characters in minor roles.

Comment: Yes, of course. That's First Edition Cthulhu by Gaslight. Here is a review: http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/11/11399.phtml